# Milk bottles and pigeonhole.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chess Master Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15903/chess-master-problem)

A child drinks at least 1 bottle of milk a day. Given that he has drunk 700 bottles of milk in a year of 365 days, prove that for he has drunk exactly 29 bottles in some consecutive days.

I think this problem could be solved by the pigeonhole principle but I am not sure.

Comment: The answer in the dupe essentially works for this.

Comment: Another answer that also works is the one that I added here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97397/combinatorics-pigeonhole-principle-question. The solution would be very similar to the answer I added there, but I think there is not enough room here in the comments to detail it. Anyway, it starts by building these sets: {1,30,59,...,668,697}; {2,31,60, ...,669,698}; {3,32,61,...,670,699}; {4,33,62, ...,671,700}; ...; {29,58,87,...,696}. There are 29 sets, in total. The first four sets have 25 numbers, and the remaining sets have 24 numbers. The rest of the solution is very similar.