# There are 50 rooms in a line. If there are 26 rooms with girls, prove there are two girls exactly 5 rooms apart.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

There are 50 rooms in a line. If there are 26 rooms with girls, prove there are two girls exactly 5 rooms apart.

My idea was place 25 girls in into pairs of rooms, and there is no scenario which there are 5 girls apart. Then, if you place one more, by pigeonhole principle, there's a girl exactly 5 away - but I want a more formal way of explaining this. Does anyone have a way? Cheers.

Comment: I think the question is still incomplete.

Comment: The description of the rooms and girls includes no geometric or topological features, so it seems to be undefined what you mean by "$5$ rooms apart", "$5$ girls apart" and "exactly $5$ away".

Comment: hi above: fixed. sorry bout that

Comment: This is same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/prove-that-2-students-live-exactly-five-houses-apart-if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hint: Color the rooms with five colors according to the remainder mod 5 of the room number.